# Virtual keyboard issue in android

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to use a Linearlayout at the bottom of the parent and just above that a scrollview with a edittext in it.
when a touch on the edittext a virtual keyboard pops up with both edittext and linearlayout aligned at the bottom.
I would like to view only the edittext and not the footer linearlayout on the top.

Is there anyway that i can get it done in android.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

add this to your activity tag in manifest

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick reply. i have tried this but it also does the same thing it takes the bottom two controls up,while i want only the selected edit text to be viewed up

Comment: Can you please try this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Answer (score 0):

Is the LinearLayout at the bottom with alignParentBottom = true? It should not, in your situation.